# How to get messages from RabbitMQ DLQ in Spring via REST API

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'm using a RabbitMq queue. So far when some error occurs messeges from queue are moved to DLQ. Now - they stay there with no action, however what I wanna to do is to create java-spring endpoint to GET all of these messeges from DLQ and print them somwhere on UI.
And I am wondering what would be the best approach to fetch this info from Rabbit DLQ directly to my code so I can either save them or send them somewhere else.

I tried to create RabbitListiner (queues = "myDLG") but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thank you for joining StackOverflow. To increase your chances of getting a response from others, I would add the code of the best attempt that you have tried.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.